# Windows 8 ..... No Module named pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using windows 8 and am trying to learn nltk. when I try to create a dispersion_plot I get an error

```
ImportError: No module named 'pylab'
```

I did a google search and found this

http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

However it seems that installing it on windows is really tough. Can anyone give me simpler instructions (like using pip) to get this installed?

Based on some of the suggestions given below I tried this

```
 D:\>d:\anaconda\scripts\pip install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

but I got an error

```
Downloading/unpacking python-numpy
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-numpy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-numpy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Abhishek\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

if you download anaconda, then you don't need to do a thing. if you want to install yourself, try:

```
pip install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got an error. I have updated my question above with the command I typed and the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward installing it on windows. As has been pointed out, something like Anaconda should have all what you need.

If not, then you can actually use the binary matplotlib installer here: http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Make sure you pick the version that matches your python installation and architecture. You should be set after that.